# Javascript Selection API :: containsNode() does not return true when span element is selected

Tags: javascript, selection, selection-api

My question is about this function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/containsNode
and I have created this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-bartik-smjt2?file=/src/index.js

code:

```js
document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<h1>Hello Vanilla!</h1>
<div>
  We use the same configuration.<s> <span id="_span"><img src="http://www.mandysam.com/img/random.jpg" id="_img" alt="" aria-label="" width="40"></span> as Parcel to bundle this </s> sandbox, you can find more
  info about Parcel.
  <h2 id="y" hidden=true>span selected</h2>
  <h2 id="z" hidden=true>img selected</h2>
</div>
`;

document.addEventListener("selectionchange", () => {
  const selection = window.getSelection();

  let span = document.querySelector("#_span");
  const foundSpan = selection.containsNode(span);

  let img = document.querySelector("#_img");
  const foundImg = selection.containsNode(img);

  let y = document.querySelector("#y");
  y.toggleAttribute("hidden", !foundSpan);
  let z = document.querySelector("#z");
  z.toggleAttribute("hidden", !foundImg);
});
```

I do not understand why I should select at least a character before and after the image so the `containsNode` returns `true` on the `span` element. Is this the expected behavior; the span element supposed to be selected whenever the `img` is selected, right?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the question itself, not only on an external site like codesandbox.io. Please read [ask].

Comment: Hello there Alex! Please take some time to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66857182/edit) your question and visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the expected behavior.

From the [specification for the Selection API](https://www.w3.org/TR/selection-api/#dom-selection-containsnode):

> `containsNode()` method
>
> The method must return `false` if the context
> object is empty or if node's root is not the document associated with
> the context object.
>
> Otherwise, if `allowPartialContainment` is `false`, the method must return
> `true` **if and only if** start of its range is before or visually
> equivalent to the first boundary point in the node **and** end of its
> range is after or visually equivalent to the last boundary point in
> the node.
>
> If allowPartialContainment is `true`, the method must return `true` if and
> only if start of its range is before or visually equivalent to the
> first boundary point in the node or end of its range is after or
> visually equivalent to the last boundary point in the node.

The interface for `containsNode()` is [defined as](https://www.w3.org/TR/selection-api/#selection-interface):

```
boolean containsNode(Node node, optional boolean allowPartialContainment = false);
```

You have to provide `true` for the `allowPartialContainment` argument if you also want to have nodes that are only partially contained considered part of the selection:

```
const foundSpan = selection.containsNode(span, true);
```

```js
document.addEventListener("selectionchange", () => {
  const selection = window.getSelection();

  let span = document.querySelector("#_span");
  const isFullyContained = selection.containsNode(span);
  const isPartiallyContained = selection.containsNode(span, true);

  let y = document.querySelector("#y");
  y.toggleAttribute("hidden", !isPartiallyContained || isFullyContained);
  let z = document.querySelector("#z");
  z.toggleAttribute("hidden", !isFullyContained);
});
```

```html
<h1>Select the text with the image</h1>
<div>
  We use the same configuration.
  <span id="_span"><img src="http://www.mandysam.com/img/random.jpg" width="40"></span>
  as Parcel to bundle this sandbox, you can find more info about Parcel.
  <h2 id="y" hidden=true>span partially contained</h2>
  <h2 id="z" hidden=true>span fully contained</h2>
</div>
```

It works with the image because `img` is is a void element (has no content) and therefore can't be only partially contained in a selection.

Comment: http://help.dottoro.com/ljphmtlx.php also shows a demo on their page of this concept.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I have already considered that. I will try to rephrase my question, let me know if it's clear: 
The span only contains the `img` element. Why when the img element is selected the `selection.containsNode(span)` returns false and it only returns true when the selections includes at least 1 character before and after the span?

Comment: This is because of how boundary points are defined. They are a tuple of a node and the offset of the selected element inside of that node. The boundary points for the selected image are `(span, 0)` and `(span, 1)` both of them being inside of the `span`.

Comment: Thanks that what I was looking for. Can you share any links on boundary points?

Comment: Ok this doesn't make sense to me.  I have an element at say, offset=3, and anchorOffset=3.  Why isn't `containsNode` returning true for the element at offset=3?  It appears selected, and I don't understand what else would need to be done to make `containsNode(elem,false)` return true.  I can't pass `true` to `containsNode` because then it returns container elements that aren't completely in the selection.

Comment: I am also going to have to filter out elements `containsNode` returns when the parent node is also returned by the selection, but that's a different matter.

Comment: more specifically, the specification says `start of its range is before or visually equivalent to the first boundary point` BUT the start of the range is EQUAL to the visually equivalent first boundary point, and likewise the end of the range is EQUAL to the visually equivalent last boundary point.  In order words, the start and end element *appear to be selected* yet `containsNode` says they are not.